# CustomAdapter with multiple getView in android

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapter

I have an activity, where in i display list of media files i.e Video, Audio, Images and Animations. On clicking the list item, (as of now Images), the activity must display all the images in the local assets folder in grid View. To do so, i use a single adapter and have a switch case in my getView() function. Depending on the options that is set in the constructor, the switch cases would execute. It works fine for the ListView display, but i am unable to display list of images in grid View. Any help would be apprecaited. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
    package com.bookshelf;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FilenameFilter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Gallery;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class MediaGalaryListActivity extends Activity implements
    OnItemClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> mGalary = new ArrayList<String>();
private Bitmap mBitArray[];
private Gallery mMediaGallery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mediagalary);
    mGalary.add("Videos");
    mGalary.add("Audios");
    mGalary.add("Images");
    mGalary.add("Animation");
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mediaGal);
    mMediaGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.mediaGallery);

    lv.setAdapter(new MediaGalaryAdapter(this, mGalary, 1));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

class MediaGalaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> mGal = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Bitmap[] mImgArray;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflate;
    private int mAdapterOpt;

    public MediaGalaryAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> gal,
            int adapOpt) {
        context = ctx;
        mGal = gal;
        mAdapterOpt = adapOpt;
        mInflate = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public MediaGalaryAdapter(Context ctx, Bitmap[] imgArray, int adapOpt) {
        context = ctx;
        mImgArray = imgArray;
        mInflate = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mAdapterOpt = adapOpt;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        int size = 0;
        switch (mAdapterOpt) {
        case 1:
            size = mGal.size();
            break;
        case 2:
            size = mImgArray.length;
            break;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        switch (mAdapterOpt) {
        case 1:
            convertView = mInflate.inflate(R.layout.medialayout, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            tv.setText(mGal.get(position));
            break;
        case 2:
            ImageView imgView;

            convertView = mInflate.inflate(R.layout.image_gallery, null);

            imgView = new ImageView(context);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(mImgArray[position]);
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            imgView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imgView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);


            break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

// For filtering the filename with extensions
class FileNamFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private String mFileExtn;

    public FileNamFilter(String extn) {
        mFileExtn = "." + extn;
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return filename.endsWith(mFileExtn);
    }
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String mediaType = mGalary.get(pos);


    String list[] = null;
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        list = assetManager.list("Immersive");
        mBitArray = new Bitmap[list.length];

        System.out.println("Length of list ="+list.length);


        for (int i = 0, idx = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        {

            if (list[i].endsWith(".png") || list[i].endsWith(".gif")
                    || list[i].endsWith(".jpeg")
                    || list[i].endsWith(".jpg"))
            {
                mBitArray[idx++] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager
                        .open("Immersive/" + list[i]));
                System.out.println("Image at position "+i+" is "+list[i]);
            }
            ;

        }
        mMediaGallery
                .setAdapter(new MediaGalaryAdapter(this, mBitArray, 2));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    build.setTitle("InProgress....");
    // build.setIcon(android.R.drawable.)
    build.setMessage(mediaType + " is Inprogress...");
    build.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = build.create();
    alert.show();
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mediaType, 30).show();
}

class MediaGalary {
    private ImageView mImage;
    private TextView mName;

    public MediaGalary(ImageView img, TextView strName) {
        mImage = img;
        mName = strName;
    }

    public ImageView getmImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public void setmImage(ImageView mImage) {
        this.mImage = mImage;
    }

    public TextView getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(TextView mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Chances of getting an answer increase if you could pin point the problem.

Comment: Yeah what's your problem? @Varsha Shankar

Comment: Problem is, when i click the list item in my list, it displays the set of images in my assets folder. On clicking again, I get an exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : bitmap size exceeds VM buget. How do I get rid of this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each application in the device will be allocated some amount of memory by the DVM. you are getting out of memory error becoz your application is exceeding the memory the allocated by dvm to ur application. for example in froyo, memory allocated for an application is 16Mb. if your application exceeding more than 16Mb, you will get out of memory error. The solution for this is you have to compress the images you are using in your application, and you have to clear all the collection you are using. try clearing all collection you are using once there job is done. you can check how much memory has been consumed by your application in ddms using heap tool. hope this will be helpfull for you.